# Autowiring does not work in spring boot hibernate validator when saving

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have created annotation constraint in spring boot application. It checks if the supplied email exists in users table. The constraint is giving NullPointerException for @autowired field.

As I understand, first time the validator is called by spring and the second time it is called by hibernate. When validator is called by spring, the @autowired field is injected successfully. When it is called by hibernate the injected value is always null. I tried field injection and by constructor.

`UniqueEmail.java`

```
@Target({FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, ANNOTATION_TYPE, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueEmailValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface UniqueEmail {
    String message() default "{validation.user.email.email_exists}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

`UniqueEmailValidator.java`

```
public class UniqueEmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueEmail, String> {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String email, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext) {
        return email != null && !userRepository.existsByEmail(email);
    }
}
```

And I have these beans for my validator with configured messageSource

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return bean;
}
```

This is my API endpoint

```
@PostMapping("/sign-up")
public void signUp(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
    // other user details related code ...
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

If I disable hibernate validator, then entity saving works. But I would like to keep it. I have also tried to set validator bean to MethodValidationPostProcessor, but it still does not work. What is the correct way to inject repository to validator? None of the solutions worked.

Comment: Your validator is not a managed bean by spring. Spring has no idea about your validator. Thats why you get null.

Comment: Could you give me any advice how to solve this problem ?

Comment: My advice would be, dont put buisness logic in a hibernate validator. The validator should check that the email format is valid, not if it already exists in the database. Spring managed means that spring instantiates the bean and uses the bean. My advice is to read up the basics of spring beans, what controller are, how autowiring works. You need to manually create the validator as a bean, configure it and then autowire will work. Its waaaaay too much work.